# Developing a SaaS application

Tags: cloud, saas

I want to develop an application that will be on the cloud.

I just need to get an idea of what to do step by step. Any diagram or flowchart type thing will work - details will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you should take a look at the Software Engineering for SaaS course from Coursera:

https://www.coursera.org/course/saas